# jquery how to make current ul visible/display block?

Tags: jquery

Im building a menu dynamically and then a sub menu inside this dynamically also.

The submenu is hidden and then when the user hovers over te main menu link the submenu appears.

what i need to do is if the sub menu li has a class 'on' then i need that submenu ul to be given the attr visible or display block?

so i need some sort of jquery when the page loads if the submenu contain li with class on then that submenu gets the attr visible?

This is my menu:

```
 <div class="sideMenu2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href>retail</a>
               <ul class="subsideMenu2">
                    <li class= "on"><a href="/portfolio/5/0">cabot circus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/portfolio/6/0">st. stephen&#39;s</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/portfolio/7/0">silverburn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/portfolio/8/0">the elements</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href>sports &amp; leisure</a>
               <ul class="subsideMenu2">
                     <li><a href="/portfolio/19/0">test</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
       </ul>  
   </div>
```

Comment: How does it get the class `on`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li.on').closest('ul').show()
```